# How to Use MatTooltip in Dynamically-Generated Div

Tags: angular

I'm simply trying to add a matTooltip to an element I've added in Typescript. Is there a way to add a matTooltip this way?

I've already added the import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip'; at the top of the .ts file, and I'm able to actually append the div itself, but neither the matTooltip nor the class I applied seem to work. According to other issues with the class, it seems using ViewEncapsulation.None will fix the problem with applying the class, but it will mess everything else up in the application. However, my main focus is just trying to get a tooltip to show up. Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

`childdiv.innerHTML += '<div matTooltip="HELLO" class="test">hello</div>';`

Comment: You can't, since mattooltip is a directive

Comment: So I can't apply a class either? I'm not sure why mattooltip being a directive prevents me from applying it to dynamically-generated elements.

Comment: you can apply class, but mattooltip is an angular directive that needs to be attached to the elements in angular way

Comment: Ok, thank you! I appreciate that.